# How to reset the length of the control of scaleLine in OpenLayers?

Tags: openlayers-2, cartography, style, mapcontrol

I want to change the style of the control of the ScaleLine,but I have no idea where to change it,anybody can give me some advice?

map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.ScaleLine());

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check out following links

http://dev.openlayers.org/addins/scalebar/trunk/examples/scalebar.html 
http://dev.openlayers.org/addins/scalebar/trunk/examples/scalebar-custom.html

will be helpful for you.

Comment: @ethelhao My Pleasure :)